# function template specialization failed?

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> 
void foo(T) {
    std::cout << "foo(T)" << std::endl;
}

template <class T> 
void foo(T*) { //#3
    std::cout << "foo(T*)" << std::endl;
}

#define TEST

#ifdef TEST
template <> 
void foo(int*) { //#1
    std::cout << "foo(int*)" << std::endl;
}
#else
template <>
void foo<int*>(int*) { //#2
    std::cout << "foo<int*>(int*)" << std::endl;
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int* p = 0;
    foo(p);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between `#1` and `#2` above? If I define `TEST`, then `#1` works, but if I comment it out, `#3` works.  Which is the right way to write function template specialization here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#1 declares a function template specialization of #3 and automatically deduces the template parameters. #2 is a specialization of the first template you defined (the one without number, let's call it #0) for `T=int*`. It can't be a specialization of #3 because replacing `T` with the specified `int*` there would lead to a `int**` parameter.

When you call `foo`, overload resolution now first picks the best fitting base template, then checks that template for any existing specializations. With `TEST` defined, there are two base templates (#0 and #3) and #3 is a better match and gets selected. Then the compiler checks for specializations of that template, and #1 is a better fit and is being called.

Without `TEST` defined, there are still two base templates (#0 and #3) and #3 is a better match and gets selected. Then the compiler checks for specializations of that template, but since #2 specializes #0 and not #3, it is not considered and #3 ends of being called.

This is the classical example of [Why not Specialize Function Templates](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm). The problems are explained in more detail there.

The simple solution is to not specialize function templates at all, but simply add new overloads for the special types:

```
// no template, just a normal function
void foo(int*) {
    std::cout << "foo(int*)" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For function template specializations you can explicitly list the template arguments but you don't have to if the template arguments are deduced. If you don't specify the template arguments, they are deduced by the compiler using the same rules as overload resolution. For deciding which function overload is to be chosen, the compiler starts with looking only at the primary templates (which are selected by some magical process in the first place). Looking at the two available primary templates

```
template <typename T> void foo(T);
template <typename T> void foo(T*);
```

the latter is a better match for a pointer argument. Once the proper primary template is found, the compiler looks for potential specializations of this primary template. However, your example #2 actually is not a specialization of function template taking a pointer argument although it involves a pointer argument. If you take the primary declaration

```
template <typename T> void foo(T*);
```

and you replace `T` by the explicitly specified template argument `int*` you get

```
template <> void foo<int*>(int**);
```

That is, the declaration

```
template <> void foo<int*>(int*);
```

is something different. You probably just want to lose the pointer when specifying the template argument:

```
template <> void foo<int>(int*);
```

Comment: Why do you say `#2` shouldn't compile? It fits the first template, `template <class T> void foo(T)` with `T=int*`.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Oh, sorry, you are right: I didn't see that there are two primary templates and the question become which of these is used. However, since the pointer version version of the primary match is a better choice, this template would be chosen even if the specialization of it is a better match: overload resolution works in terms of the primary templates. Once the function template is decided, the proper specialization is selected. I guess, I should edit the answer to reflect this...

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell which function #2 is supposed to specialize, or exactly how the extremely complicated overload resolution rules would select the function to call.

I do know that you most often don't *need* to specialize functions, but can rely on overloading instead. To get a function for `int*` you just need

```
void foo(int*) {
    std::cout << "foo(int*)" << std::endl;
}
```

A non-template function will be preferred over templates, as long as the parameter matches.

Comment: There are some contexts where it is convenient or necessary to specify the template argument(s). The obvious place where it is necessary to specify the arguments is if the template argument is non-deduced. Places where it is convenient is when you need to direct the argument to an appropriately converted type. When you want to explicitly specify the argument you often can't use overloading.